# React Native TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.Animated.Text.propTypes.style') in iOS simulator

Tags: react-native, animation, text, typeerror

This is the code where I use Animated.text only here. It was working but when I installed react-native-render-html library after that this error comes. However, I have uninstalled that library but still this error comes.

```js
return (
  <View style={styles.tabBar}>
    {props.navigationState.routes.map((route, i) => {
      const color = Animated.color(
        Animated.round(
          Animated.interpolate(props.position, {
            inputRange,
            outputRange: inputRange.map(inputIndex =>
              inputIndex === i ? 255 : 0
            ),
          })
        ),
        0,
        0
      );

      return (
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={styles.tabItem}
          onPress={() => this.setState({ index: i })}>
          <Animated.Text style={{ color }}>{route.title}</Animated.Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      );
    })}
  </View>
);
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HLW3U.png)

Comment: can you show stack trace for that error?

Comment: Please click on Error Image for stack trace of error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An issue Concerning this problem is opened on github

[NativeBase/issues/3109](https://github.com/GeekyAnts/NativeBase/issues/3109)

To solve this:
Look for 'Animated.Text.propTypes.style' in node_modules and delete it

( It exists in deferent files on your node_module )