# undefined is not an object (evaluating '_reactNative.Animated.Text.propTypes.style')

Tags: reactjs, xcode, react-native

I encountered this error when upgraded react-native version to **0.63.0**. I searched this error but according to other sources it is either problem in react-native-material-dropdown or in react-native-material-textfield. I have also tried to look for Animated.Text.propTypes in node_modules but it does not exist. Although i found it in main.bundle.js in ios folder.
My Pod file is as following:

```
    require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'

platform :ios, '10.0'

target 'Project_name' do
  permissions_path = '../node_modules/react-native-permissions/ios'
  pod 'RNVectorIcons', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons'
  pod 'Permission-Camera', :path => "#{permissions_path}/Camera.podspec"
  
  config = use_native_modules!
  use_react_native!(:path => config["reactNativePath"])

 
  use_flipper!
  post_install do |installer|
    flipper_post_install(installer)
  end

end
```

Package.json file is as following:

```
{
  "name": "Project_name",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.12.0",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^3.0.1",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.0",
    "accordion-collapse-react-native": "^0.3.2",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.16.1",
    "debounce": "^1.2.0",
    "fetch-timeout": "0.0.2",
    "http": "0.0.1-security",
    "https": "^1.0.0",
    "install": "^0.13.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "moment": "^2.27.0",
    "native-base": "^2.13.14",
    "npm": "^6.14.8",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.2",
    "react-native-af-video-player": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-asset-library-to-base64": "^1.1.0",
    "react-native-autocomplete-input": "^4.2.0",
    "react-native-aws3": "0.0.9",
    "react-native-background-upload": "^6.1.0",
    "react-native-beautiful-video-recorder": "^2.0.1",
    "react-native-camera": "^3.38.0",
    "react-native-check-box": "^2.1.7",
    "react-native-checkbox": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-cookies": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-datepicker": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-device-info": "^6.0.1",
    "react-native-dropdown-picker": "^3.6.8",
    "react-native-event-listeners": "^1.0.7",
    "react-native-fs": "^2.16.6",
    "react-native-gallery-manager": "^1.0.9",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.7.0",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^2.3.3",
    "react-native-keep-awake": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.2",
    "react-native-keychain": "^6.1.1",
    "react-native-material-buttons": "^0.6.0",
    "react-native-modal-datetime-picker": "^8.9.3",
    "react-native-modal-dropdown": "^0.6.2",
    "react-native-navybits-date-time-picker": "^1.2.3",
    "react-native-permissions": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.0",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.7",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.10.1",
    "react-native-stopwatch-timer": "0.0.21",
    "react-native-touch-id": "^4.4.1",
    "react-native-video": "^5.1.0-alpha8",
    "react-native-video-editor": "^0.2.0",
    "react-native-walkthrough-tooltip": "^1.1.10",
    "react-navigation": "^4.4.0",
    "realm": "^6.1.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "7.11.5",
    "@babel/runtime": "7.11.2",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "1.1.0",
    "babel-jest": "25.5.1",
    "eslint": "6.8.0",
    "jest": "25.5.4",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.59.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.13.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: Same problem is mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61201873/react-native-typeerror-undefined-is-not-an-object-evaluating-reactnative-ani/63559884#63559884)

Comment: @AymenAmara i appreciate your help but i did'nt find anything related to Animated.Text.propTypes.styles in node_modules.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Anyone suffering from this nightmare it was react-native-material-button that was causing this issue. Turns out that vs code do not completely search node modules.